# Why can't I get the static text to print in my panel using wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

Here is my code

```
import wx

class justin(wx.Frame):


    def __init__(self,parent,id):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,'frame', size=(800, 500))
        panel=wx.Panel(self)
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        self.box1=wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "type number")
        self.box2=wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, "type number")
        self.box1.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
        self.box2.SetBackgroundColour("gray")

        siz=wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        siz.Add(self.box1, 1)
        siz.Add(self.box2, 1)
        panel.SetSizer(siz)

        button=wx.Button(panel, label="enter", pos=(250, 200), size=(100, 50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.yesitstrue, button)

    def yesitstrue(self, event):
        a=(float(self.box1.GetValue()))
        b=(float(self.box2.GetValue()))
        answer = a+b
        wx.StaticText(self.panel,id, answer, pos=(200, 100))



if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=justin(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

what I'm trying to do is get text from two text boxes and add it then print it in a GUI format. When the program gets to the part on static text it says panel doesn't exist.
I would like any help if any other bugs are found please let me know because i really need it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code:

- `panel`:  The `panel` doesn't exist error is because in your code it's a variable inside the `__init__` method that is no longer available in the `yesitstrue` method. To fix that, you have to assign it as an instance attribute in the `__init__` method like this: `self.panel = panel`. After that, you'll be able to access it in the `yesitstrue` method using `self.panel` as you're already trying to do.
- `id`: The `nex_StaticText` expected argument 2 of type `int` means that the second argument, `id`, isn't of the expected type. Note that `id` is a python built-in function and this is what is causing problems. The solution is similar to the one for `panel`: assign `id` argument as an instance attribute like this: `self.id = id`. After that, call `wx.StaticText`using `self.id` instead of just `id`.
- `answer`: The string or unicode type required means that you're passing something that isn't really text. In the code, `a` and `b` are converted to `float` and answer is their sum. Hence, it's also a `float`. To fix this, convert `answert` to a string using `str` and call `wx.StaticText`using `str(answer)`

Comment: so now I dont get that error anymore but i get                TypeError: in method 'new_StaticText', expected argument 2 of type 'int' I have never seen this error and dont know what it wants me to do

Comment: There were a couple more problems that are explained in the edited answer. This time, you should get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks guys I had only seen jcollado's first post and learned the rest just by messing around with the program